# Accessing instances in GUI file while instances are declared in another file

Tags: java, swing, class, oop, instance

I'm learning OOP in `Java`. I'll explain my problem first, code below.
I have 3 seperate file (User.java, UserGUI.java and UserStart.java).

User.java has the code containing the User class with the default getters and setters.
UserGUI.java only exists out of items creating the GUI. UserStart.java has the code containing the main to run the program.

Now I'm trying to select a UserID in the `JList` in UserGUI.java and I want to show the surname and name in the `JTextField` below the `JList`.

User instances are made in UserStart.java and I'm stumped how to access them in UserGUI.java...

Is there anyone wanting to help me with this? Thank you in advance!

Below is the class of User.java:

```
public class User {

    private String userId;
    private String surname;
    private String name;

    public User(String userId, String surname, String name) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getuserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setuserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getsurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setsurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public String getname() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setname(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Below is a piece of code from the userGUI.java:

```
final JList<?> userList= new JList<Object>(addresses);
    userList.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
            if(!e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                String userId = (String) userList.getSelectedValue();
                System.out.println(userId);
            }
        }
    });

JTextField userText = new JTextField(10);
userText.setEditable(false);
```

Below is the file UserStart.java:

```
public class UserStart {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String userId, surname, name;
        String[] userIds = {"a206", "a207", "a208", "a209"};

        User u1 = new User(userIds[0], "a", "w");
        User u2 = new User(userIds[1], "b", "x");
        User u3 = new User(userIds[2], "c", "y");
        User u4 = new User(userIds[3], "d", "z");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the simple way (which will suffice) is to pass the 'data' to the GUI on construction

```
class UserGui
{
    private User[] user;

    public UserGui(User[] users)
    {
        this.user = user;

        initializeComponents();
    }

    // ...
}
```

then in your main

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    User[] user = new User[10];

    // setup user array ...

    UserGui gui = new UserGui(user);
}
```

for larger more complicated programs/applications you should look in to using [MVC](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-142890.html) as an approach which allows you decouple UI from Data.

Answer (score 1):

For example in the User.java class you can create a static verctor with all users created (add each user there in the constructor):

```
    import java.util.Vector;
    public class User {

        private String userId;
        private String surname;
        private String name;
        public static Vector<User> users=new Vector<User>();

        public User(String userId, String surname, String name){
        this.userId=userId;
        this.surname=surname;
        this.name=name;

        User.users.add(this);
        }

   }
```

then you can access any created user in any class like this:

```
User.users.get(i).getname();
```

depending on your problem, you should note the index somehow. the first created user will be 0: users.get(0), second one will be 1, and so on

for example if you want to display all users, then in a loop like this:

```
String name=null, surname=null;

for(int i=0;i<User.users.size();i++){
    name=User.users.get(i).getname();
    surname=User.users.get(i).getsurname();
    //do something with you data before moving to next user
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to use an array iso vector?

Comment: it is possible, but vectors are 10000 times more comfortable. they have loads of methods (like add, get, size and etc) which make your life easy. with array for example before adding each new user, you will have to find out the size of array, then add it to the next position. vectors do this stuff automatically. try it with vector, if something isn't clear I'll explain it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your constructor should have the same name as the class. Something like this:

```
public User(String userId, String surname, String name) {
    this.userId = userId;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.name = name;
}
```

If you want to add the text to a `JTextBox`

if you have 1 textbox:

```
textbox1.setText(""+userList.getSelectedValue().getName() + ""+userList.getSelectedValue().getSurname())
```

if you have 2:

```
textbox1.setText(""+userList.getSelectedValue().getName());
textbox2.setText(""+userList.getSelectedValue().getSurname());
```

I haven't tested it, but it should work.